# What does "Invoice Unit Price" property on Inventory do?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

I tried to get more information from Sitecore developer reference documents, but I could not find much about where and how the "Invoice Unit Price" property on inventory is used.

Comment: Are you reffering to the sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/users/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/work-with-inventory.html or something more specific?

Comment: @CristiVulturar Yes, it's in the documentation, and I see it on Inventory biz fx view when I associate a product, but I did not find any other reference.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/101/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/work-with-inventory.html) says:

*Optionally, you can change the default **Invoice Price Currency** value, and enter the **Invoice Unit Price**, **Invoice Price Currency**, and whether the item is available for preorders or backorders, the dates it is available, and the limits for preorders and backorders.*

Also there is a note:

```
Preorder and backorder functionality is not fully implemented in this release (10.1).
```

So looks like those properties were introduced early then functionality was implemented.